# Criterion for using "Riemann" or "Riemannian" in terminology

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, terminology

**Question:**

Is there any criterion for using **Riemann** or **Riemannian** in terminology?

---

For example, Riemann occurs in these phrases:

Riemann surface, Riemann curvature tensor, Riemann-integrable, Riemann sum,  Riemann sphere, Riemann-Roch theorem, Riemann Hypothesis...

... while Riemannian occurs in these phrases:

Riemannian geometry, Riemannian manifold, Riemannian measure, Riemannian metric...

Especially, why it's Riemann surface but Riemannian manifold?

---

Related links:

[Why is “abelian” infrequently capitalized?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/)

[Mathematical adjectives that bear famous mathematician's names](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402846/)

[Mathematical concepts named after mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/)

[Mathematician's names in structures.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671534/)

[How mathematical theorems and concepts gain their names?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822899/)

---

Edit:

$1.$ From the comments, I realize it partly follows from conventions and habbits, though it may cause trouble when searching and might not be very friendly to non-English users. For example:

English: Riemann Surface, Riemannian Geometry (inconsistent)

French: surface de Riemann, Géométrie riemannienne (inconsistent)

German: Riemannsche Fläche, Riemannsche Geometrie (consistent)

Japanese: リーマン面, リーマン幾何学 (consistent)

Chinese: 黎曼曲面, 黎曼几何 (consistent)

$2.$ As the answer mentioned, when it's related to some definitions or properties, it's often "-ian", e.g. Riemannian metric, Gaussian process, Artinian ring, Noetherian ring.

$3.$ There're some typos about "Riemann" in this website.

Comment: This is because English is a flexible language :) In German, Riemann surface is "Riemannsche Fläche", consistent with Riemannian manifold, "Riemannsche Mannigfaltigkeit". But note that "Abelsche Gruppe" also in English is never "Abel group", but Abelian group or abelian group.

Comment: Has showed by the many links in yoyr post, natural language is not always "logical"; habits and conventions rule.

Comment: I cannot resist to make a remark here. On this site  "Riemann surface"  is often misspelled as "Reimann surface", e.g., title of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902696/which-of-the-following-function-are-reimann-integrable-on-the-interval-0-1), or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035126/reimann-zeta-function) second line of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557690/where-is-the-second-countability-of-a-riemann-surface-used-in-finding-an-exhaust), etc.

Comment: And of course [Cauchy-Reimann](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997869/mapping-and-cauchy-reimann-conditions) as well, [reimann-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563048/proving-that-if-2-functions-are-reimann-integrable-over-a-subset-then-so-is-the), [Reimann Mapping Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004818/without-using-reimann-mapping-theorem-how-to-argue-conformal-maps-does-not-exi/3004827), [Lower Reimann Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577082/lower-reimann-integral?rq=1) etc.

Comment: French isn't consistent either, but it seems to be consistent with English : we have "surface de Riemann" but "variété Riemanienne" for instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is largely an English/linguistics question, but it requires some math knowledge to answer. I disagree with the idea that this is *only* because of the flexibility of English in using nouns as adjectives. For most of the examples listed in the OP, there is a difference between the two lists.

As a litmus test, if you would want to say "non-Riemann(ian)" then it has to be "Riemannian" since "non-Riemann" sounds weird to a native English speaker (cf. abelian group vs. Lebesgue integral).

#### Type 1:

The Riemann integral is one of many integrals, and it's the one associated with Riemann. We wouldn't usually look at a bunch of integrals and say "these 3 are Riemann(ian) and these 4 are non-Riemann(ian)"

A Riemann surface is a special sort of object, and one wouldn't have occasion to say "sure it's a surface, but this one is not Riemann(ian)".

The Riemann Hypothesis is a particular thing. We do not sort hypotheses/conjectures into the Riemann ones and the non-Riemann ones.

Etc.

#### Type 2:

Riemannian geometry is distinguished from other geometric structure in (differential) geometry. There is a book called non-Riemannian Geometry for this reason.

A metric on a manifold may or may not be positive definite, so we can ask whether a metric is Riemannian or not ("non-Riemannian metric" is rare, but would be understood).

Smooth manifolds can always be given a Riemannian metric, but they're not Riemannian manifolds until we pick one. We don't really talk about non-Riemannian manifolds, but "pseudo-Riemannian manifold" is close.

Comment: It sounds like the matter is really one of uniqueness, in the sense that there are many Riemannian manifolds, but there is only one Riemann integral?

Comment: Actually, there is no book called "non-Reimannian Geometry."

Comment: @KCd fixed, thanks